# Docker: executng commands with non-root user inside container

Tags: docker

I have a custom docker container based on the Debian Wheezy image from docker registry. I want to use it with vagrant (with docker-provider) so I create a new user (vagrant user) the image is saved in our repository.
everything is ok on my local machine, I can simply use it, su vagrant is work just fine. 
My machine is:

```
Linux ###### 3.13.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 1 12:19:51 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is no problem at all with some machines. 
but on other machines

```
Linux ###### 3.13.7-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 24 19:44:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
Linux ###### 3.8.0-32-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 22:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have this problem :

```
docker run -ti example.com:5000/wheezy /bin/bash
root@385af4fd6f17:/# su vagrant
Cannot execute /usr/bin/zsh: Permission denied
root@385af4fd6f17:/#
```

The exact same commands on my machine and some others have no problem at all. 
In the last two machines which have problem, root user work without any problem, but I can not run any command on non-root users (I've created another fresh user in current session and no luck)

Comment: Could you show your Dockerfile? I suspect that you need to add a step to create the vagrant user within the image.

Comment: There is no docker file at all. I just pull an image from the base repository, modify it, tag it for my own repository and then push it to my local repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was beacuse of this bug : https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4068

Machine with devicemapper as storage driver are ok, but the aufs storage has this bug. 
changing the docker storage to devicemapper (docker -d -s=devicemapper) OR using the git version (currently 0.9.1 has this bug) fix this issue.