# Cannot use docker without sudo privilege after following the official guide

Tags: docker, sudo, privileges, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to pull a Docker image by this command
`docker pull rabbitmq`
then I got this error
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/nickie/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

When I ran `sudo system ctl status docker` the status was green (active and running)

I've then followed all the threads I could find on this platform, but no solutions solved my issue.

When I run `sudo groupadd docker` following [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) the console replied `groupadd: group 'docker' already exists` but even when I uninstalled Docker completely from Ubuntu and reinstall it from scratch, the issues reappeared.

Yes I can add "sudo" before any docker command I try to execute and the issue could go away, but I remember I did not have to do this in previous times when I installed Docker on other computers. So I need an explanation why this issue happened and how I could fix it.

Other threads I've visited:
[Docker: executng commands with non-root user inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892374/docker-executng-commands-with-non-root-user-inside-container?rq=3),
[How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1),
[Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke),
[Docker Permission Denied During Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68628732/docker-permission-denied-during-setup)

Comment: Your local environment is configured to use Docker Desktop, but it's not running.  When you use `sudo` the root environment doesn't have that configuration and you use the "normal" Docker daemon.  The linked question has details on switching back.

Answer (score 0):

Your user likely isn't in the docker group (see with `groups`)

```bash
usermod -aG docker $USER
```

If you have done this and it still doesn't work, you may need to sign out and back in or start a login shell to refresh the permissions

Comment: I ran the command and then restarted my computer but that didn't work. Is that what's supposed to be done?

Comment: ah, I'd avoid Docker Desktop, which is a system for taking money from companies and install `docker.io` instead